# Can I gain access to the Thieves Guild treasury?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've completely finished the Thieves Guild quest line, which means I'm now Guild Master. Up until this point, I've had access to a very empty treasury. Now that I'm leader, I've noticed that the treasury has now been locked again and needs a key in order to be opened.

Is there a way to gain access to the treasury? If so, what kind of loot is hiding behind the locked door? In other words, is it worth breaking in?

[image]

Comment: Weird, why did it relock on you?  In my game it was left wide open, I eventually got tired of looking at the empty containers and closed the door myself.

Comment: In both my games, it's been wide open long before it should have been. I think this door is just generally bugged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. Your share of 'The Treasury' will show up in the Tribute Chest, but there's no extra loot hiding in the Vault now that you're guildmaster, even if you noclip in there.

Comment: So disappointing :/ Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The room should remain locked until you have completed "Under New Management". You know you'll have totally completed the Thieves Guild questline if you have the "Guildmaster's Armor". This also involves completing the 20+ or so radiant quests from Delvin and Vex in "Restoring the Thieves Guild to it's Former Glory."

Once you do get access to this room, however, it is just as empty as Mercer left it. Which makes me wonder where he stashed it...